If $R / I$ is flat then $IJ = I \cap J$ for any ideal $J$.
Given a unital commutative ring $R$ and ideals $I, J$ of $R$ with $R / I$ being a flat $R$-module show that $IJ = I \cap J$.
I've gotten to the S.E.S
$$0 \to J / IJ \to R / I \to R / (I + J)$$
as suggested in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PQ, but I'm unable to see how to finish off the proof. A hint would be very appreciated.

In general what is the kernel of the map $J/IJ\to R/I$?

Ah, great. Thank you for the hint; I have solved it now.
